# Ignore magento admin directory in GeoIP Htaccess Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, magento, geolocation, geoip

I've got a magento install that is using the htaccess mod_geoip to redirect people from specific countries to other store fronts. It's working like a charm (after I got it to ignore javascript and skin files), but I'm going to be having someone from Australia input some orders into the backend of magento.

The issue is that they can't access the main backend at store/index.php/admin (they are rewritten to austore/index.php/admin) and when they go to put orders in, they are missing some integral components of the order process which I think is due to the url being rewritten to austore/index.php/admin. Wondering if there is a way that if the request uri is store/index.php/admin that they won't get rewritten. My code is below from my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(skin|js) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}     ^(AQ|AU|MY|BV|BN|BN|MM|KH|CN|CX|CC|CK|GQ|FJ|PF|GU|GW|HM|HK|ID|KI|KR|KP|KR|LA|MO|MY|MH|FM|MM|NR|NC|PG|NZ|NU|NF|PG|CN|PH|PN|WS|SG|SB|KR|LK|BN|TW|TW|AU|TH|TL|TK|TO|TV|VU|VN|VN|WF)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/store(/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /austore%1 [L,R]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from this, http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/secure-your-magento-admin/ you can use the same rewrite logic in what you want to do.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/(index.php/)?(admin|custom_extensions_go_here)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/downloader/ [NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}     ^(AQ|AU|MY|BV|BN|BN|MM|KH|CN|CX|CC|CK|GQ|FJ|PF|GU|GW|HM|HK|ID|KI|KR|KP|KR|LA|MO|MY|MH|FM|MM|NR|NC|PG|NZ|NU|NF|PG|CN|PH|PN|WS|SG|SB|KR|LK|BN|TW|TW|AU|TH|TL|TK|TO|TV|VU|VN|VN|WF)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/store(/.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /austore%1 [L,R]
```

Just bear in mind, doing this through `.htaccess` could potentially cause some bizarre issues in the long run with 3rd party extensions, that have custom admin routes (that are not prefixed with /admin) break. So just be mindful of this.

I would advocate the use of a Magento extension (PHP based), mod_geoip store switcher - as then you can make it apply only to the frontend area of the Magento store (to prevent the potential errors I've described above)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It doesn't seem to be working though, the base login page for the store is still changing to the region specific store. Does it matter that my store isn't in the root but in root/store? We did initially look at some php store switchers, but we weren't satisfied with their implementation.

Comment: Well the code is right, so I can only assume your `RewriteBase` is potentially causing an issue with the store being in a subdirectory. PHP based is the far more reliable method - assuming your PHP developer is competent.

Comment: This is our RewriteBase /store/. We'll take a look at php based redirect again. Do you feel there is any degradation in speed for the php based lookup?

Comment: PHP is fast enough. But your bottleneck will be that a **good** PHP implementation should be in a custom Magento extension, so it requires the Mage instance to be created (`Mage::run()`) before it can carry out your modules requirements, this will add a small overhead, probably noticeably (slightly) slower than `.htaccess`. I realised I might have typo'ed in my comment, try replacing the `NC,OR` with `NC` and try again - seems a shame if your "simpler" current implementation otherwise works well.

Comment: Bummer, still doesn't seem to be working. Feel like it's really close, but just can't figure it out.

Comment: @coloradohiker I've edited the answer above, changed ordering and added `/store/` - give that a try ;)

Comment: That worked! Seems like once it hit the geoIP redirect it was too late to ignore those directories. Nice work!